Angular: complex grouped looping in HTML template
I'm recreating an existing application written in Flask, to Angular. I have a page which generates a list of events, grouped by country and region. This is what the output looks like.

Here's the relevant code from the Jinja template
<div class="convention_list">
    {% set ns = namespace() %}
    {% set ns.active_country = '' %}
    {% set ns.active_region = '' %}

    <b>Listing {{context.conventions|length}} events</b>

    {% for convention in context.conventions %}

        {% if ns.active_country != convention.country %}
            {% set ns.active_country = convention.country %}
            {% set anchor_link = ns.active_country|lower|replace(' ', '-') %}
            <a name="{{anchor_link}}"></a>
            <h3><a href="#{{anchor_link}}" class="anchor-link" title="Link to this section">{{ns.active_country}}</a></h3>
        {% endif %}

        {% if ns.active_region != convention.region[1] %}
            {% set ns.active_region = convention.region[1] %}
            {% if ns.active_region %}
                {% set anchor_link = ns.active_country|lower|replace(' ', '-') + '-' + ns.active_region|lower|replace(' ', '-') %}
                <a name="{{anchor_link}}"></a>
                <h4><a href="#{{anchor_link}}" class="anchor-link" title="Link to this section">{{ns.active_region}}</a></h4>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}

        <div class="event>
            <h3>{{convention.name}}</h3>
            <div class="location">
                {{convention.city}}{% if ns.active_region %}, {{ns.active_region}}{% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

In my initial research it appears that Angular templates cannot set intermediate variables within a loop. But as you can see in the sample code, I need to be able to know when country and region changes so that I know whether to output headings.
The data coming in will be ordered by country > region > start date, like so:

Given the limitations of the template language, what is my best option for displaying this data?
Possible idea. Right now I have a simple array of events, grouping happens at the template level. But what if I pre-grouped into countries/regions. So rather than returning this:
events = [
 {event},
 {event},
]

I return this instead:
events = [
   '<country>': [
      {event},
      {event},
   ],
   ...
]

This alternate idea might work, but then what would my Angular return type look like? Right now it's easy: Convention[]. Thoughts?

From your screenshot, it looks like you are only grouping by country, not by region.  It looks to me like you are basically hiding the country header when the current item's country equals the previous item's country.  You can achieve this using something like this:
<ng-container *ngFor="let convention of context.conventions; let i = index;"><h3 *ngIf="context.conventions[i-1]?.country !== convention.country">{{ convention.country }}</h3></ng-container>
